# comparing user input with a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to prompt the user to type four full names that exist in a text file, then compare the user input with the list of full names to see if they exist and display what the user inputted in the order entered. Every time I run this code the error keeps saying object is not subscriptable.

What's going wrong?

```
class Voting:

    def __init__(self):
        with open("PresidentCandidates.txt", 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        self.Candidates = set([s.strip() for s in lines])
        print(self.Candidates)

    def presidentvoting(self):
        userinput = input("Enter 4 names in the order of preference, who you will like to be president ")
        userInput = list[userinput]
        if userInput in self.Candidates:
            print(userinput)
        else:
            print("fail")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
userInput = list[userinput]
```

you need to use normal brackets rather than square brackets. i.e.

```
userInput = list(userinput)
```

This should fix the error. However you have another bug in your code. To fix this, change:

```
userInput = list(userinput)
if userInput in self.Candidates:
    print(userinput)
else:
    print("fail")
```

to

```
userInput = userinput.split(' ')
for i in userInput
    if i in self.Candidates:
        print(userinput)
    else:
        print("fail")
```

This is because, you need to check each item in the `userInput` list against your text file list, rather than comparing the whole `userInput` list against your text file list.

This code fix assumes that your input is separated with spaces.
e.g. "President1 President2 President3 President4"

If you are using another separator, edit:

`userInput = userinput.split(' ')`

to

`userInput = userinput.split(<INSERT SEPARATOR HERE>)`

EDIT: 25/01/20 [REQUESTED NOT TO PRINT USERINPUT 4 TIMES]
change:

```
userInput = userinput.split(' ')
for i in userInput
    if i in self.Candidates:
        print(userinput)
    else:
        print("fail")
```

to

```
userInput = userinput.split(' ')
for i in userInput
    if not (i in self.Candidates):
        print("fail")
        return
print(userinput)
```

Comment: Thanks that did help but it's now printing the four names I typed down 4 times.eg ['DioneHester', 'AlyssaYates', 'ElliotBrennan', 'TylaChilds']
['DioneHester', 'AlyssaYates', 'ElliotBrennan', 'TylaChilds']
['DioneHester', 'AlyssaYates', 'ElliotBrennan', 'TylaChilds']
['DioneHester', 'AlyssaYates', 'ElliotBrennan', 'TylaChilds']
How do I make it so the loop only runs once?

Comment: That's because you have ```print(userinput)```, in ```if i in self.Candidates```

Comment: See the edit above. When the function fails it prints "fail" and stops executing i.e. ```return```. If everything is correct it prints userinput at the end of the function. Please let me know if this is not what you wanted. NOTE: The loop still runs four times